# To Do List item update in database not working with Django

Tags: python, django, database, string, save

I want to finish my To-Do app. However, I still can't edit an item properly. My idea was to update the database by picking the particular item and overwrite its information with `.save()`. Could someone figure out the correct `update()` function to make it work?

Here is my code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.details, name="details"),
    path("add/", views.add, name="add"),
    path("delete/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.delete, name="delete"),
    path("edit/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("update/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.update, name="update")
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Aufgabenzettel(models.Model):
    Aufgabeselbst = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Aufgabeselbst}"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Aufgabenzettel

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/index.html", {
        "Aufgabenliste":Aufgabenzettel.objects.all()
    })

def details(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/details.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Aufgabe = request.POST["Hinzufügen"]
        Aufgabenzettel.objects.create(Aufgabeselbst=Aufgabe)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/add.html")

def delete(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    aufgabenzettel.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

def edit(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel
    })

def update(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Aufgabe = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
        Aufgabejetzt = request.POST["Bearbeiten"]
        Aufgabejetzt.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        Aufgabe = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
        return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html", {
            "details":Aufgabe
        })
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Meine Aufgaben</h1>
    <ol>
        {% for Aufgabeselbst in Aufgabenliste %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'details' Aufgabeselbst.id %}"> 
                    {{ Aufgabeselbst }}
                </a>
                <form action="{% url 'delete' Aufgabeselbst.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Löschen</button>
                </form>
                <form action="{% url 'edit' Aufgabeselbst.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" value="{{ details }}">Bearbeiten</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    <h2>
        <a href="{% url 'add' %}">Neue Aufgabe erstellen</a>
    </h2>
{% endblock %}
```

**add.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Füge eine neue Aufgabe hinzu</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="Hinzufügen" placeholder="Neue Aufgabe">
        <button type="submit">Hinzufügen</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**edit.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'update' details.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="Bearbeiten" value="{{details}}">
        <button type="submit">Bearbeiten</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**details.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ details }}</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I get the this error: *'str' object has no attribute 'save'* relating to `Aufgabejetzt.save()` in my **views.py**. I know that Aufgabejetzt is actually a string object and therefore could not be connected to the database. But that's the point... I don't know how to connect those two properly...

I appreciate every kind of help!
[image: Traceback]

Comment: I have just seen that someone tried to reply. Sadly, the comment disappeared after I edited the post... :( Could you repost it?

Comment: Can you post your traceback? Post as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
Aufgabejetzt = request.POST["Bearbeiten"]
Aufgabejetzt.save()
```

You assign a string to your object which does not have the save method on it.

You probably want:

```
Aufgabe.Aufgabejetzt = request.POST["Bearbeiten"]
Aufgabe.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! You solved the error but it somehow does not update the database... When I press the *Bearbeiten* button I am just redirected to the index where the original task is still there. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Just found out that it should be `Aufgabe.Aufgabeselbst = request.POST["Bearbeiten"]` ;) Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it a lot!